# Cannot input data when using tools e.g erase, but adding data to map works?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

None of the data is available to use when inputting for tools use, but it all is available when just adding it?

Basically alot of my data is loaded into arcgis. When adding new data to my current map, there is no problem. All my downloaded data is readily avalable, but when it comes to using the existing data loaded onto arcgis already, when I want to for e.g intersect two layers, I cannot input anything, because as soon as I click input features, the data just isn't there anymore. And this happens for all other tools as well.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more detail than 2 sentences, maybe a screenshot?

Comment: OKay sorry, so basically alot of my data is loaded into arcgis. When adding new data to my current map, there is no problem. All my downloaded data is readily avalable, but when it comes to using the existing data loaded onto arcgis already, when i want to for e.g intersect two layers, i cannot input anything, because as soon as i click input features, the data just isnt there anymore. And this happens for all other tools as well.

Comment: This is what i mean, once i click to input data, theres just nothing in the files that are supposed to hold it. I did notice that it is saying input coverage and not features, maybe i should change something around, to make it accpet features?

Answer (score 3):

Two possible reasons: 
1) I can see the tool you are using is for coverage that is a different format dataset than shapefiles or file/personal geodatabase types (it used to be the native ArcInfo dataformat). So make sure you are using the appropriate tools

look at the snapshot below, it explicitly says Input Features not Input Coverage..
[image]

2) You might not have edit access to the data.

Comment: So how do i change that then?

Comment: did you check if you have access to editing your data first? I mean is it on a server with no write access to you, or is it in a read-only folder?. If you have access. Next did you use Arc Toolbox > Analysis Tools>Overlay toolbox or another set of tools?

Comment: yes i did use that, i do have access! omg you're right, ive been using coverage tools this whole time! thanks, im switching to analysis tools now. Thaksn gaian!